# How can I pop up modal for each hour?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-7

I want to show popup modal for each hour like it is starts from 10 to 6, to write logged in users report. It should works like if it is 10 o' clock popup will come and user write their report and close it. after 1 hour i.e. 11 o' clock again popup will show.

I am using laravel 7, javascript and jquery. Any of these language it is convenient for me. please help me.

this the code I used so far

** javascript code to popup modal **

```
setInterval(function () {
       get_task_data();
    }, 3600000);
  
    
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
    });

   function get_task_data() {
    
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route('project.employee.task') }}',
            type:'GET',
            data: { }
        }).done(function(data){
             $('#myModal .modal-body').append(data);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    }
```

But I want to popup modal exactly 10 0' clock , 11 o' clock and so on till 6 0'clock.

**Edited**

I want to send 'desktop notification' for each hour "Please send your report" something like this. How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @kiner_shah I used setInterval 
` setInterval(function () {
       get_task_data();
    }, 50000); `

Comment: Please edit the post with the relevant code and do highlight what issues you face, if any.

Comment: @kiner_shah edited, please check it

Comment: What you need to do is: on page load get the current time, say it is 9:45. Calculate number of minutes till 10:00, in this case it is 15 minutes, so call `setInterval` accordingly. Then at 10:00, when the function is called, inside the function call `clearInterval` followed by `setInterval` again but this time with timeout 3600000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you ok, you can use Window setInterval() method

How  to use ?

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    // Call your modal popup init function here__
}, 3600000);
```

3600000 = 3600 seconds = 60 minute = 1 hour

Learn more about set interval [Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

---

Following example, code will use to show the alert popup in each one hour

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    alert("Hello");
}, 3600000);
```

**Updated Code Snippet**

This code will use to display popup modal exactly 10 0' clock , 11 o' clock and so on till 6 0'clock.

```js
var currentDate = new Date(); // get your current date and time__
var curentHour = currentDate.getHours(); // get Hours of your current time__
var curentMinutes = currentDate.getMinutes(); // get minutes of your current time__

var intervalId = null;
var varCounter = 0; // count the display times, and set initial value
var displayTimes = 9; // between 10'O clock to 6'O clock modal has to display 9 times

// stop function arround 6'O clock 
var varModal = function(){
     if(varCounter < 10) {
          varCounter++; // you can remove this code
          alert(varCounter + 'time'); // you can remove this code
         
          /* your code goes here */
          
     } else {
          // stop modal duisplay after 9 times, it's mea after on 6'O clock 
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          alert('Stop will start on next day'); // you can remove this code
     }
};

/*
* display modal arround 10'O clock, 
* This function will trigger after each one hour, 
* So you have to set value 9, then only it'trigger arround 10'O clock
* -------
* If you want to trigger this modal arround 9'O clock, you have to check with value 8
*/
  
  
if(curentHour >= 9 && curentMinutes > 0){
  intervalId = setInterval(varModal, 3600000);
}
```

**For Quick test**

Update the following code from above mentioned code sippet

```
   if(curentHour >= 9 && curentMinutes > 0){
      intervalId = setInterval(varModal, 3600000);
    }
```

Changed to

```
var localTimeInHours = 11; // have to mention your current time hours
var hoursForValidation = localTimeInHours - 1;

   if(curentHour >= hoursForValidation && curentMinutes > 0){
      intervalId = setInterval(varModal, 30000);
    }
```

I did following changes in above mentioned code

1. I changed 3600000 into 30000 (30000 = 30sec) this will used to
   display pop in each 30 sec
2. Update localTimeInHours varaible with the hours value from your
   current time, please check the following example:

- If your current loacl time is *11.15am* update value localTimeInHours* variable value should be *11*
- If your current loacl time is *10.00am* update value *localTimeInHours* variable value should be *10*
- If your current loacl time is *10.00pm = 22.00pm* update value
  *localTimeInHours* variable value should be *22*
- If your current loacl time is *6.40pm = 18.40pm* update value
  *localTimeInHours* variable value should be *18*

Comment: But I want to popup modal exactly 10 0' clock , 11 o' clock and so on till 6 0'clock. how it can be done?

Comment: @developer3onecityPlease check the updated code snippet..

Comment: this function it will work once when loading, otherwise it will not check
` if(curentHour >= 9 && curentMinutes > 0){
  intervalId = setInterval(varModal, 3600000);
} `

Comment: @developer3onecity, I think this solution will work. try changing the interval timeout value to some smaller number like `60000` (1 minute).

Comment: @Katheer, I think you may need to modify this slightly. Like if the script is run at 9:45, it should initially set the interval value to 15 mins and from next time on wards 1 hour.

Comment: ` if(curentHour >= 9 && curentMinutes > 0){
  intervalId = setInterval(varModal, 3600000);
} ` this whole function should I put inside setInterval ??

Comment: @developer3onecity if you want to do quick test, change 3600000 into 30000 (30000 = 30sec), and change value 9 by "your current-time - 1", that's mean your current time is 11.15am you have to change value 9 into 10 ( 11 - 1 ), DId you got it? 
```if(curentHour >= 10 && curentMinutes > 0){
  intervalId = setInterval(varModal, 30000);
}```

Comment: @developer3onecity to do quick test, check **For Quick test** section in  the comment

Answer (score 0):

Use an interval with something like 100/200ms delay then check if the curr minutes are 0. In order to avoid multiple calls check if the current H-m is different from the last called.

```js
let last = null;
setInterval(function() {
  const d = new Date();
  const curr_hm = `${d.getHours()}-${d.getMinutes()}`;
  if (d.getMinutes() == 0 && curr_hm != last) {
    console.log('Do task here!');
    last = curr_hm;
  }
}, 200);
```

Comment: why you used this  const curr_hm = `{d.getHours()}-{d.getMinutes()}`;  ? can you explain me

Comment: Thats just a string like H-m ( Hours - minutes ). Without that the function ll be called every 200ms in the trigger minute causing unwanted multiple calls.

Comment: for first time it works but sencond time onwards 'curr_hm != last' it will be equal, because assigning 'last = curr_hm;' in first true condition. so it is not working second time onwards.

Comment: Oh wait, fixed my code, was missing $ in string interpolation.